# Speed ​up the moving average

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The code below considers the moving average, depending on a few conditions. And if the date in the row is less than the specified one (startdate), then it returns the current value of the column. Everything is cool, but it works slowly (i have >200000 rows), can this be accelerated?

```
startdate = pd.to_datetime('2019-06-02')
df['RES1_1Y'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: (df.loc[
        (
            (df.DATE_G < x.DATE_G)
            & (df.DATE_G >= (x.DATE_G + pd.DateOffset(days=-365)))
            & (df.ID1_G == x.ID1_G)
            & (df.ID_C_T == x.ID_C_T)
        ),
        "RES",
    ].mean()) if x.DATE_G > startdate else x.RES1_1Y,
    axis=1,
)
```

I was offered to use Rolling_mean, but I do not understand how to do this with the conditions.
Example data:

```
DATE_G     ID1_G ID_C_T RES RES1_1Y
03.06.2019  35802   1   1   
04.06.2019  13592   2   0   
05.06.2019  28267   2   0   
06.06.2019  36327   1   0   
07.06.2019  28267   1   0   
08.06.2019  78317   1   0   
09.06.2019  13101   2   0   
10.06.2019  28267   2   1   0
11.06.2019  46752   2   0   
12.06.2019  36320   1   1   
13.06.2019  28108   2   0   
14.06.2019  72815   1   1   
15.06.2019  31819   1   0   
16.06.2019  28267   2   0   0.5
17.06.2019  14953   1   0   
18.06.2019  23381   1   0   
19.06.2019  29260   1   1   
20.06.2019  35498   1   0   
21.06.2019  28267   2   0   0.333333333
22.06.2019  5058    2   0   
23.06.2019  4003    5   0
```

Comment: if you provide some sample data it will be much easier , youll need to take the numpy approch, and use vectors instead of apply
with sampled data i could write something..

Comment: _"Depending on a few conditions"_ , what are these conditions?

Comment: conditions:

(df.DATE_G < x.DATE_G)
            & (df.DATE_G >= (x.DATE_G + pd.DateOffset(days=-365)))
            & (df.ID1_G == x.ID1_G)
            & (df.ID_C_T == x.ID_C_T)

Comment: I provide sample data